# AWS how do I get notified when lambda is disabled | Alert when lambda trigger get enable or disable

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudtrail

Some one disable my lambda trigger(Kinesis event)
Need alert or notification if someone enable or disable lambda trigger.